# Problem 2-6 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The problem says

> Let $P:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^{k+1}\setminus
>  \{0\}$ be a smooth function, and suppose that for some $d\in
>  \mathbb{Z}$, $P(\lambda x)=\lambda ^dP(x)$ for all $\lambda \in
>  \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$. (Such a function is said to be homogeneous of degree d.) Show that the map $\tilde{P}:\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n\to \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^k$ defined by $\tilde{P}([x])=[P(x)]$ is well defined and smooth.

To show that it is smooth is alright for me, I combine Examples 1.5 og 1.33 to conclude it. But I do not know how to show that it is well-defined.

Comment: Well defined means that any representative in the equivalence class has the same image. So you don't get $x$ and $\lambda x$ going to different places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $[x]=[y]$ in $\mathbb{R}P^n$, then there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $y=\lambda x$, therefore:
$$P(y)=\lambda^dP(x).$$
Whence, $[P(x)]=[P(y)]$ in $\mathbb{R}P^k$.

In other words, the image of $[x]$ under $\widetilde{P}$ does not depend on $x$ the representant of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Let $[x] \in \mathbb{PR}^{n}$. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n -{0}$ be a representative for the equivalence class. For every $\lambda \neq0$ we have that $P(\lambda x)=\lambda^d P(x)$. Thus $[P(x)]=[\lambda^d P(x)]$. So the function is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Let $[x]=[y] \in \Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^n$, then $x = \lambda y$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}^\times$, and we have

\begin{align}
\tilde{P}([x])&=[P(x)] && \text{by definition}\\
&=[P(\lambda y)] && \text{as $[x]=[y]$}\\
&=[\lambda^d P(y)] && \text{by assumption}\\
&=[P(y)] && \text{the equivalence class is unaffected by mult by scalars}\\
&=\tilde{P}([y]) && \text{by definition}
\end{align}

as needed, and $\tilde{P}([x])$ is well-defined.